# Visit New File doesn't create new directories

Tags: osx, files

Maybe I am completely misremembering but I am sure that Emacs used to create missing directories when using Visit New File command.

Let say that `~/Documents` exists. And I want to create a new file in `test/test.lisp` inside of `~/Documents`. I would `C-x C-f` `~/Documents/test/test.lisp` and a new empty buffer would be created. And as soon as `test.lisp` is saved. Emacs would prompt for an OK to create `~/Documents/test`.

Now I just get `Opening directory: No such file or directory, ~/Documents/test`

Is this the default behavior? Or is something wrong on my end. I suddenly can't remember.

Comment: It is the default behaviour (at least for me for the last 30 years or more).

Comment: Uhh, I thought the same as @FranBurstall, but when I tried it just now again, I get a `Directory ... does not exist; create? (y/n)` prompt and if I say `y`, the non-existing intermediate directories are created. The code is in `basic-save-buffer`, ll. 5717-5729 in `files.el` (or thereabouts - my version 30.0.50 is from upstream Git). AFAICT, it does not depend on any options, unless you've done something to disable the `y-or-no` function.

Comment: TIL!  But this only happens when you save the buffer.  The `find-file` part of the story creates the buffer but messages: `Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents`.

Comment: I'm on 30.0.50 also.